# background color hover fade effects

Tags: html, css

Using this css code

```
#onec-fourth:hover {
  background-color: #F36DE1;
  color: white;
}
```

I want that when I move the mouse off the object (`#onec-fourth`),
for the background color & the color text will persist for 1 second.

Because right now, when I move my mouse off it is stopped.

How do I make the `:hover` effect persist a short duration?

Comment: I'm assuming English is not your first language? Do you mean that you want the `background-color` to *remain coloured* for one second after the mouse leaves the element?

Comment: If i understand your question then use interval for that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8eBvj/..       This fiddle might give you an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of task can be easily realized with a simple CSS `transition`, no Javascript is needed (unless you need to support older browsers, but the basic effect will work anyway):

**Example**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nzLkf (tested on Firefox29 and Chrome35)

---

**CSS code**

```
#onec-fourth {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed #ddd;
  -webkit-transition: all 0s linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 0s linear 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 0s linear 1s;
  transition: all 0s linear 1s;
 }

#onec-fourth:hover{
  background-color:#F36DE1;
  color:white;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

---

For a fade-out effect (after 1 second) see instead http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AkCcm

(use `transition: all 1s linear 1s` and `transition: all 0s linear 0s` on `:hover`):
just play with with `transition-duration` and  `transition-delay` values as you prefer, until you achieve the optimal result.

Further information on CSS transitions can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: @user3706524 you're welcome. if this answer was useful you could upvote and/or mark it as accepted.

Comment: here the code http://jsfiddle.net/96jYZ/1/. I want it will be dimmed and become like the background's color and not will be more and more bright.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUUVS/1/)**

```
var self;
$('#onec-fourth').mouseover(function(){
    self = $(this);
    self.css('background-color','red');
}).mouseleave(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
       self.css('background-color','blue');
    },1000);
});
```

Using jQuery **[setTimeout()](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/)** , **[mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)** and **[mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**. Check the links for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple demonstration of the technique that might help you:

```
#onec-fourth {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* vendor prefixes stripped for brevity;
       sets the transition for the background-color property: */
    transition: background-color 1s linear; 
    transition-delay: 1s; /* delays that transition for 1 second */
}

#onec-fourth:hover {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4X8Qh/1/).

References:

- [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).
- [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply more styles than just one you may use addClass/removeClass:

```
<style>
.hov {
  background-color:#F36DE1;
  color:white;
}
</style>
```

and jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#onec-fourth").mouseenter(function () {
   $("#onec-fourth").addClass("hov");
});
$("#onec-fourth").mouseleave(function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
    $("#onec-fourth").removeClass("hov");
   }, 1000);
});
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zSJa/8/